# How to solve ADE

Tags: difference-equations

I want solve these Algebraic differential equations, with arbitrary constants and initial conditions

```
(*Define the system of differential equations*)
eqns = {\[Theta]'[
 r] == (-1 - \[Beta]0*(\[Theta][r] - \[Theta]0)*(M[r] + 
      4 Pi*pp[r]*r^3)/\[Beta]0 *(r^2 - 2*r*M[r])), 


 M'[r] == 4*Pi*r^2*dd[r], \[Nu]'[r] == 
2 (M[r] + 4*pp[r]*r^3)/(r^2 - 2 M[r] r)};
\[Nu]'[r] == 2 (M[r] + 4*pp[r]*r^3)/(r^2 - 2 M[r] r)};
```

with algebric

```
(*Define the algebraic equations*)
algEqns = {\[Beta][r] == \[Beta]0*Exp[\[Nu]0 - \[Nu][r]], 


 dd[r] == -cnst*PolyLog[3/2, -E^\[Theta][r]], 


pp[r] == -cnst*PolyLog[5/2, -E^\[Theta][r]]};
(*Set the initial conditions for \[Theta],M,and \[Nu]*)
ics = {\[Theta][10^-5] == \[Theta]0, 
   M[10^-5] == 10^-10, \[Nu][0] == \[Nu]0};
(*Set the boundary condition for \[Beta] at r=0*)
bcs = {\[Beta][0] == \[Beta]0};
```

it show error like Differential-algebraic equations must be given as initial value problems.

Comment: What is domain for your solution? Is it `{r, 0, 10^-5}`?

Comment: Did you try `DSolve`?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide the complete code that created the error you mentioned.  Otherwise, we cannot help you.  By the way, there is no need to treat this as a Differential Algebraic Equation.  Just substitute the values of `algEqns ` into `eqns`.

Comment: Yess Domain is from `{r,0,10^5}` or take mock domain

Comment: No didn't try DSolve @U

Comment: @bbgodfrey algebraic are not independent rather depend upon differentials.